# When Creating New Workbook, Paste Select Cells into Columns

Tags: vba, excel

This script copies all cells from C2:C3 for all sheets in the workbook. I would like for it to ignore all hidden sheets. Also the current script is pasting into the next available row when I am trying to paste into the next available column.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sample()
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LRowO As Long, LRowI As Long

'Set the output sheet
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

For Each wsInput In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsInput.Name <> wsOutput.Name Then
        With wsInput      
            Set rng = .Range("C2:C3")
            rng.Copy
            With wsOutput             
                LRowO = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A" & LRowO).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next wsInput

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsM As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Set wsM = Worksheets("Master")
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("New_Part")
    ws1.Copy After:=Worksheets(ws1.Index)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(ws1.Index + 1)

    lr = wsM.Cells(wsM.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsM.Range(wsM.Cells(lr, 1), wsM.Cells(lr + 1, 1)).Value2 = ws2.Range("C2:C3").Value2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this Paul. The first half is a command button that allows me to create a copy of my New_Part tab when selected, thus generating the New_Part (2). I have a tab named "Master" that is already created. The issue I am running into is when I run the VBA to create a new New_Part (2) or New_Part(3), etc. I want it to paste the C2:C3 from the newly created sheet into the next empty column of "Master".

Comment: Thanks for the update Paul. The script is running into an issue with how it is calling the cells. Is there a way to have that script read only the values in the cell instead of the formulas? Also can it read the page of source?

Comment: To copy just the values replace the last line `ws2.Range("C2:C3").Copy Destination:=wsM.Cells(lr, 1)` with `wsM.Range(wsM.Cells(lr, 1), wsM.Cells(lr + 1, 1)).Value2 = ws2.Range("C2:C3").Value2`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "can it read the page of source?". Can you reformulate the question?

Comment: When trying to copy the contents of C2 and C3, how can it read just the values and not the formulas? I tried to run your last change and it runs but nothing is pasting into the "Master" sheet. Thanks again for all of your help Paul.

Comment: Hm...I am still trying to change this even after the last edit and the script is running but nothing is pasting in the "Master" sheet. I ran it 10-15 times for both the original sheet as well as for the copy and still nothing :(...

Comment: can you send me your test file at dexxus at rogers.com

Comment: Hey Paul. I was able to fix the script, but I have now run into another issue where it is copying the hidden sheets. It is also now pasting into the next available row as opposed to column. I have tried to shift it to columns but I am running into an issue. Any ideas? Thanks for everything thus far.

Comment: Hi @DanteSmith: your question is becoming too dynamic (you're not supposed to change the initial requirements as you build your code). You should accept the answer if it solved the initial problem, and if you have new issues open a new question (divide and conquer mothod)

Comment: OP: see [here](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-to-discourage-chameleon-questions) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) regarding chameleon questions.

Comment: I actually salved the issue outside of this solution but I will accept it to satisfy your and CBRF23s response to "chameleon" questions. It wasn't a different question but more of a difference in how it was formatted but thank you for your time.

Comment: You should post your own answer that solved your problem, and accept it, such that if someone else that has a similar issue, your answer will help solve their problem as well (you don't have to accept my answer if it didn't provide a reasonable solution). The point is to accept the most generic and helpful solution to a specific issue (without too many adjustments)